# Repository queries and Entity instance variable names

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use methods in my Spring Repository class like this:

```
public
interface
ToolRepository extends Repository<Tool, Long>
{
    public Tool findByNumber(String inNumber);
}
```

With an Entity column defined like this. Note that although I explicitly name the column "number", Spring (or Hibernate) sees the actual member variable name "mNumber" and fails to generate the proper query.

```
import javax.persistence.Column;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Tool")
public
class
Tool implements Serializable
{
    @Column(name = "number")    protected Integer   mNumber;

    public Integer  getNumber()                 { return mNumber; }
    protected void  setNumber(Integer inVal)    { mNumber = inVal; }
}
```

Is there an annotation to specify the name that Spring should use when interpret queries?

This code is built with spring-boot `1.4.3.RELEASE`, and I'm using Postgres.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the "correct" `@Column`, are you importing the correct annotation!?

Comment: @luk2302, I'm using javax.persistence.Column

Comment: @Surace that should not be required, it should work exactly as OP expects it to.

Comment: Remove your mNumber's  getter and setter and let IDE to generate again.

Comment: yeap as suggested by @SaiYeYanNaingAye , recreate the setter/getter for the `mNumber` to match exactly the variable's name , and the same for the `Repository` class , your query should be named `findBymNumber`.

Comment: @AntJavaDev, I'm not using an IDE, just Gradle from the command line. What would that accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the findBy to the following:

```
public interface ToolRepository extends Repository<Tool, Long>
{
    public Tool findByMNumber(String mNumber);
}
```

If you change the parameter name, then you need to use @Param annotation and specify the property name.

Reference:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

**If you dont want to change the method name, use @Query annotation:**

```
public interface ToolRepository extends Repository<Tool, Long>
{
    @Query("from Tool where mNumber = :number")
    public Tool findByNumber(String number);
}
```

If needed, generate getter and setter for mNumber. You can generate it through the IDE.

Comment: Right, I don't want to do that.

Comment: you mean you dont want to change to findByMNumber ?

Comment: I want to write "findByNumber", and I want to leave the member variable "mNumber," and the column name "number". It seems this isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks, prem. That's more verbose than I would have liked (I'd prefer to specify it as a single name attribute in an annotation on the field), but that gives me a way to do it. Thanks!