# Spring's findByColumnName returning empty list

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I need to retrieve a list of `Category` from the DB on the basis of value of column called `owner`. Here is my `Category` -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
class Category(@Column(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
                     @Id @GeneratedValue(strategyGenerationType.AUTO)
                     var id: Long = 0,

                     @Column(name = "category_owner", nullable = false)
                     @field:NotNull(message = "Please assign an owner")
                     var owner: Long?,

                     @Column(name = "category_name", nullable = false)
                     @field:NotEmpty(message = "Please assign a name")
                     var name: String?)
```

Here is my interface which defines the function `findByOwner` -

```
interface CategoryRepository: JpaRepository<Category, Long> {
    fun findByOwner(categoryOwner: Long): List<Category>
}
```

However, when I call the method, I get no response. I have made sure that the DB has correct data and I'm providing the correct owner Id. Have even invalidated the cache etc. What could be going wrong?

EDIT:

After `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` -

`findAll()`

```
 Hibernate: select category0_.category_id as category1_0_, category0_.category_name as category2_0_, category0_.category_owner as category3_0_ from categories category0_
```

`findByOwner()`

```
 Hibernate: select category0_.category_id as category1_0_, category0_.category_name as category2_0_, category0_.category_owner as category3_0_ from categories category0_ where category0_.category_owner=?
```

EDIT 2:

Turns out that my implementation was fine all along. The bug was in my `service`.

Comment: Can you do a `findAll()` and check if it is returning data and at least one returned record contains `owner` value you using in the above query?

Comment: `findAll()` is working as expected.

Comment: That is good news and rules out any basic errors.  Now can you add `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` to your `application.properties` and tell me what query is generated for `findAll` and what query is generated for `findByOwner()`. You can update the question with outcome as commenting with the result will be difficult

Comment: Done. I can see that in `findByOwner()` the ownerId is not present.

Comment: Sorry. yours answers are diversing as the second query is supposed to be against `Category` entity. I recommend you run the queries directly against database and see what is coming up

Comment: Updated it for categories.

Comment: I am run out of ideas now. Both queries are same except for the `where` condition and `where` condition` is correct for the second query

Comment: No problem. I'll try other answers.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are passing the `category_owner` column value as parameter to `findByOwner` right (not `category_id`)?

Comment: Yes. I'm passing the `category_owner` column value.

Answer (score 1):

Create your named method according with the name of the column.

```
fun findByCategoryOwner(categoryOwner: Long): List<Category>
```

Or use @Query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_owner = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
fun findByOwner(cateogryOwner: Long): List<Category
```

Comment: The first option did not work. But, surprisingly, even the native query did not work. I now think the problem is something else because when I execute the same native query in my DB's GUI tool, it works.

Answer (score 1):

- Can you put a breakpoint in `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution` class and when you execute `findByOwner`, it will come here.

[image]

- When it reaches this breakpoint, select the `query.createQuery(accessor).getResultList()` and evaluate to see what value is returned by `hibernate` for `spring-data-jpa` to use

Comment: I really appreciate you taking so much time trying to find a solution. However, it turned out that the bug was in my service. The `findBy..` was working fine all along. The problem was somewhere else.

Comment: No worries. Debugging is your friend. Even the frameworks are written by another developer so debug :)

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41375431/repository-queries-and-entity-instance-variable-names) should help you. It appears to be happeing because of the `parameter name` mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

At least in java you need to provide the id in the method name:

```
**fun findByOwner_Id(categoryOwner: Long): List<Category>**
```

So change it from `findByOwner` -> `findByOwnerId`.

Comment: This does not work, unfortunately. Refuses to build.

Comment: I edited the answer @krtkush. I tried it locally and it was asking for that underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Use camelCase to name your variables in Entity class then jpa will auto recognise the column name

```
findByCategoryOwner(String categoryOwner)
```

If you still wish to have underscore in your column names then try this

```
findByCategory_Owner(String categoryOwner)
```

I haven't tried the second option though

Comment: I tried the second way. But, unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: refer this [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) it has to do something with different column name in DB and different property name in Entity class, IMO both should be same for JPA to understand